# Xpage custom inotes configuration to get profile document field

Tags: xpages, customization, lotus-notes

I have customized the inotes,as I wanted to add a button in "mailread",I mean inside the toolbar when the user opens the mail.as shown in image.

[image: custom-button]

The fuctionality behind the this button is I wanted to go to other window with specified or hard Coded database name to open in othe window.
The code in Custom_js_Lite
code:

```
 function Custom_Scene_Actions_Lite(s_MenuID)
{
 if (-1 == s_MenuID.indexOf("mailread"))
        return false;

    // Add the button
    var add1 = [{title:"custom-button", find_id: "print",class:"test", id: "sync", before: false,
        action:"openDatabase{}", help_text:"custom-button" }];
    addActionsLite( s_MenuID, true, add1);
}
   // Calling function onclick.
function openDatabase(){
      var unids = API_GetSelectedDocs_Lite();
      var server = location.host;
      var temp = location.pathname.substr(1, location.pathname.length);
      var pos = temp.toLowerCase().indexOf(".nsf");
      var database =  temp.substr(0, pos + 4);
   window.open("http://localhost/example.nsf/home.xsp?server="+server+"&db="+database+"&mailDocId="+unids);
```

In above code window.open, Opens the given link with selected unids which is getting from "API_GetSelectedDocs_Lite();" but the database name is hard coded that is "example.nsf";

So Instead of hardcoding the database name,I am just wondering to save the database name once profile document of that curent user's mail database, So it would help me get the database name from profile document to open it according.

I am not sure,If I can retrieve the the profile document field in subforms, custom inotes.

I need some idea how to retrieve the profile document in mail database with custom_js_lite.

Or i would really like to know if there is any other way to acheive this.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for this.
I have just retrieved the profile document named "iNotesProfile" and add the new field in it "db_name" from my xpage button the code to update it profile document is:

```
    var currdb:NotesDatabase = session.getDatabase(session.getServerName(),"mail/abc.nsf");
    var doc:NotesDocument = currdb.getProfileDocument("iNotesProfile", "");
    doc.replaceItemValue("db_name",database.getFileName());
    doc.save();
```

This script edits the "iNotesProfile" profile document of the current user and sets the current database name inside the "db_name" field. Now we have set the database base in document which can be used from the mail database.

Now the task is to get the database name on click of custom-button.In Custom_js_Lite the code is:

```
 function Custom_Scene_Actions_Lite(s_MenuID)
    {
     if (-1 == s_MenuID.indexOf("mailread"))
            return false;

     // Add the button //

        var add1 = [{title:"custom-button", find_id: "print",class:"test", id: "sync", before: false,
            action:"openDatabase{}", help_text:"custom-button" }];
        addActionsLite( s_MenuID, true, add1);
    }

function openDatabase(){
    var unids = API_GetSelectedDocs_Lite();
    var server = location.host;
    var temp = location.pathname.substr(1, location.pathname.length);
    var pos = temp.toLowerCase().indexOf(".nsf");
    var database =  temp.substr(0, pos + 4);
    var mailFilePath = API_GetMailfilePath_Lite();
    var db_name = '@{{@GetProfileField("iNotesProfile";"db_name")};jsData}';
        if(db_name == ""){
           alert("Database is not configured! Contact Administrator.");
        }else{
           window.open("http://localhost/"+db_name+"/home.xsp?server="+server+"&db="+database+"&mailDocId="+unids);
        }
```

So we are now able to find the database name which is stored in iNotesProfile document by `@{{@GetProfileField("iNotesProfile";"db_name")};jsData}` and can be use it to go to that database.